reboot via script run by cron
I'm going nuts over something seemingly simple.
I want to run a script every minute which reboots when it finds something in a log.
It simply does not run via cron.
My script in /home/root/resetiferror.sh
#!/bin/bash

tail -fn0 /var/log/messages | while read line ; do
echo "${line}" | grep -i "failed to read" >> /var/log/resetiferror
if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
echo "$(date) found so restart" >> /var/log/resetiferror
/sbin/reboot
fi
done

This is my crontab:
1 * * * * timeout 5s /home/root/resetiferror.sh >> /var/log/resetiferror.log 2>&1

I made it executable
It DOES work with
/bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; /home/root/resetiferror.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1)"

Or is there an easier script to do a reboot when 'failed to read' found in the log?

What are the contents of /var/log/resetiferror.log? Are there any errors?

Your shebang looks off.  Try changing it to #!/bin/bash.  That said your example is using /bin/sh which may or may not be bash depending on your system configuration.    You might also try checking your  script using https://www.shellcheck.net

With 1 * * * * your script will always be executed one minute after the hour. Replace 1 with * to get it executed every minute. See man 5 crontab for more details on a system with a common Linux derivative.

@larsks nope nothing, completely empty.

@j_b sorry, it is there, didn't copy it here.. tried shellcheck: nothing special to report, only info's

@Cyrus Thanks, changed. Still doesn't work though.

@larsks sorry, not true, just rebooted and now every minute de cron runs i get: /bin/sh: timeout: command not found

That suggests something is awry with your $PATH. What if you use the full path to timeout?

This seems like a bad way to do things. It's only going to be watching the log for the first 5 seconds after the script starts; if the message appears in the log between runs --i.e. sometime other than those 5 seconds -- the script won't see it, and it won't trigger a reboot. I think it'd be much better to have the script run continuously.

changed crontab, i now have: @reboot /home/root/resetiferror.sh >> /var/log/resetiferror.log 2>&1 and it works! but now it says it is already rebooting, but it does not. When i log in en echo a 'failed to read' in messages log it does reboot. does it need different rights?
